# Common words not showing up in FULLTEXT search results

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am using Full Text searching for a website I am making to order a users search query by relevance. This is working great with one problem. When a search term is populated in my table more than 50% of the time, that query is ignored. I am looking for a solution to NOT ignore words that are in more than 50% of the rows of a table.

For example, in my "items" table, it may look something like this:

```
item_name
---------
poster 1
poster 2
poster 3
poster 4
another item
```

If a user searches for "poster", the query returns 0 results because it appears too many times in the table. How can I stop this from happening?

I've tried using IN BOOLEAN MODE, but that takes away the functionality I need (which is ordering by relevance).

Here's an example of my SQL:

```
SELECT item_title
FROM items
WHERE MATCH(item_title, tags, item_category) AGAINST('poster')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recompile MySQL to change this. From the documentation on [Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

> The 50% threshold for natural language searches is determined by the particular weighting scheme chosen. To disable it, look for the following line in storage/myisam/ftdefs.h:
>
> ```
>    #define GWS_IN_USE GWS_PROB
> ```
>
> Change that line to this:
>
> ```
>    #define GWS_IN_USE GWS_FREQ
> ```
>
> Then recompile MySQL. There is no need to rebuild the indexes in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Barmar. Where would I go about finding "storage/myisam/ftdefs.h"? I am using XAMPP/phpMyAdmin and can not find the file/folder!

Comment: I still can't seem to find "storage/myisam/ftdefs.h". I tried manually searching and using the search bar but still can not find it. The link you provided showed a Linux command. Is there something similar for Windows?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe XAMPP doesn't include source code, so you need to download that by hand to recompile.